# App to send message when battery is low?

Tags: android, notification, battery

If a parent wanted to make sure they could contact their child at any time then they would appreciate an app stored on the child's phone which would send an SMS or email message anytime the battery fell below a certain level. Whenever this would happen they could call their child and ask if they could charge it at a power outlet or else tell them to come back home.

Does such a mobile phone app exist?

Comment: AFAIR that was part of several [Child protection](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/childprotect) apps. But never having used any of those, I cannot remember which one it was. There was even one where you could block the child's device if the child didn't pickup your call – with the only option left to him/her being calling back to have it unlocked :)

Answer (score 3):

I recently developed [My Battery Is Dead](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.mitchk.mybatteryisdead) for Android to solve this exact problem. Please let me know if you are missing any features or find any bugs.

- Completely free
- No ads
- Material design
- Contact multiple recipients
- Adjust the battery level notification threshold
- The battery monitor can be paused

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Battery Low Email Notification](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.codeandroid.batterylowemail&hl=en):

- gratis
- background service that sends an email from your Gmail account to the same account whenever the battery level is low (15%).

[image]

Comment: While certainly an easier option than the Tasker way, I would never trust a 3rd party app with my google password even though it says no special permissions.

Comment: @killjoy use a different Gmail account, then set up auto forward

Comment: now why didnt i think of that ..brilliant...and to think I was doing the same over the years for testing apps..thanks for reviving the idea !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Scripting Layer for Android (SL4A)](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) + [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) (3 USD), and follow [these instructions](http://tasker.wikidot.com/automatic-email-low-battery):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [Tasker](http://market.android.com/detailshttp://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)

Install it on your kids phone and make a simple profile to do what you need.

Or a better way would be to use 
Tasker+Tasker app factory (which is sister app for Tasker, to make android apps)

With these two apps you can make very very light weight app really very easily on your android phone.

And install the app you made to your kids phone.